# C code for evaluating static code analysis tools

Tags: gratis, c, code-analysis, source-code

So, I am switching back to C coding soon. I have previous experience of Gimpel Lint and Splint, but would like to check out a few others.

Does anyone know of some C code which is specifically designed to test the capabilities of C static code analyzers?

That is to say, some code which deliberately accesses freed memory, reads beyond the end of arrays, unreachable code, etc, etc.

I would like to use it to evaluate C static code analyzers, to help me chose one.

Gratis, please, preferably Windows, but I will also accept Linux.

---

That is my on topic question. I don't suppose I would complain if there were some off-topic comments comparing such analyzers, pointing to websites, comparisons, recommendations, ease of setup/use, etc  ( wink ;-)

Comment: If it is any help I have had a co-worker or two who writes just the sort of thing that you are looking for - ALL of the time.  If it was not for copyright issues I could send you megabytes of examples.

Comment: Lolx - (+1) I generally write my own - but not deliberately

Comment: If you are coding Open Source projects you will find it hard to beat Coverity for static analysis, free Cppcheck is worth a look as well but the bees knees for embedded C code is LDRA - LDRA is anything but free though.  One of the best of course is `gcc -Wall -Werror` then fix things!

Comment: @Mawg Just to give you some ideas... [List of C/C++ tools for static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B)

Comment: Yup, I know (tahnks anyway, +1) - but but by the rules of this site I can't ask for a "best", so I will evaluate them all & see what I feel good with

Comment: Mawk, even if including it were your "on-topic question", I'm not sure about that it really is. This site is about recommending *software* – and yes, that includes libraries for development. But IMHO not code fragments. As reference: [Is asking for sample, illustrative code on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/185) says: *Questions shouldn't ask primarily for code*. So I'd consider this off-topic, sorry.

Comment: I did think about that before posting, but I realized that, as you say, many people here ask for libraries (*). What are they, but source code? This site is for `Software Recommendations` and I am asking the members to recommend some software. Maybe we should rename the site to `Application Recommendations`?  ;-)  If I want to be pedantic, I can say that I am not asking for a code snippet, but for a complete test suite. - where else can I ask?   (*) there was a site for library recommendations proposed on Area 51 not long ago, but it seems to have disappeared :-(

Comment: The only current answer to Izzy's referred question says "I would feel no except in the context of describing something that's part of the answer - for example, illustrating how a specific language/compiler combination solves a specific issue" - I want some s/w to illustrate how a static code analyzer solves the specific problem of errored code.

Comment: @Izzy That meta discussion doesn't apply directly: Mawk is asking for a code base, not for sample code. I think this warrants a new meta discussion.

Comment: OK, @Gilles & Mawg – I've retracted my vote then (Mawg: sorry for the mis-interpretation – though the "where else can I ask" argument I don't really count ;)

Comment: Thanks, Izzy. I still think it ok, although I can understand possible objections. Btw, programmer's won't entertain it ... http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/can-i-ask-for-source-code-on-this-site/7415#7415

Comment: @Mawg could simply ask for software that exercises software analysis tools, and then this question is just fine; "source code an optional plus".    I supplied an answer which consists of exactly such software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Julia test set](http://samate.nist.gov/SARD/testsuite.php)  built by NSA, available from NIST, is intended to be a broad spectrum set of tests to enable comparing various analysis tools using a standardized descriptive vocabulary.

There is a set of tests for C/C++, and another set of tests for Java.

My company has used it to test our CheckPointer dynamic analysis tool for C.  With tens of thousands of individual tests, it seemed pretty thorough.

The NIST site at the link contains a variety of other test sets contributed by a wide variety of authors.  AFAIK, these are all available as downloads for no charge.  Pick your poison :-}

Answer (score -1):

This test suite from Toyota contains invalid memory access, overflows, etc. They are conveniently placed in separate files:

https://github.com/orbitcowboy/itc-benchmarks/tree/master/01.w_Defects

They were used to find out the false positive/negative rate of some static code analysis tools.

BSD License