# Free and easy to use C/C++ static code analyser and memory debugger for absolute beginners on Windows

Tags: windows, c++, c, visual-studio, memory-management

There are tools like Valgrind, which are available on Linux, Paid PVS Studio, but nothing I know or have used is easy to use. IDEs like VS Code come with support for debugging, but I specifically want to check for memory related issues. Don't want to go for Visual Studio, as don't want to install large software.

I've read [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20074/75088) answer, but more options are welcome. There is an absolute scarcity of beginner friendly tools for C/C++ on Windows.

Comment: If your program is platform-independent, you can use Valgrind on a VM or WSL.

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan The thing is, I use a windows computer and I'm not so learned as to write platform specific code. I don't want to run Linux on a VM and then use Valgrind over there.